# mandrill not working with string type content, fetched from database

Tags: php, mandrill

I am trying to set a mail using mandrill. I am fetching some blog content from database and sending it to mail. When I am adding the title and body field of database columns it's creating problem.Else it's working fine with integer values.

This is my code what I am trying :
The mail content :

```
 $record .= '<tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-size: 16px; color: rgb(215, 215, 215);  padding: 15px 12px 0px;" align="center">
                                via
                                <a href="'. $Notify->getHref($subject) .'"  style="color: rgb(0, 153, 0); font-size: 16px;">'.$Notify->userDisplayName($subject).'</a>(@'.$subject->username.')
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            '.$photo.'
                                            <td style="padding: '.$padding.' ; vertical-align: top;">
                                                <a href="'.$link.'" style="color:rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 24px; font-family: &quot;Impact&quot;">'.$blog->title . '</a>
                                                <p style="margin-top:0px;color:rgb(140, 140, 140); font-size: 15px; font-family: &quot;Arial&quot;">
                                                ' . $des .' 
                                                </p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>';
Code for mandril :              
                    try {
                            $mandrillApiKey = $Notify->getSetting('mandrill.api.key');
                            $mandrill = new Mandrill($mandrillApiKey); 

                            //  Getting the Subject of the Mail Template
                            $templateDetails = $mandrill->templates->getList($mandrillTemplateName);

                            $message = array(
                                'subject' => $templateDetails['subject'],
                                'from_email' => $templateDetails['from_email'],
                                'to' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'email' => 'myemail@email.com',
                                        'name' => $Notify->getTitle($user)
                                    )
                                ),
                                'merge_vars' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'rcpt' => 'myemail@email.com',
                                        'vars' => array (
                                            array(
                                                'name' => 'content',
                                                'content' => $record,
                                            ),
                                            array(
                                                'name' => 'day',
                                                'content' => $day,
                                            ),                                          

                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            );

                            $template_content = array();
                            $mandrill->messages->sendTemplate($mandrillTemplateName, $template_content, $message);
                            echo 'mail hasbeen sent';

                        } catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {
                            //echo 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();
                            // A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_Unknown_Subaccount - No subaccount exists with the id 'customer-123'


                            throw $e;
                        }
```

Here If I echo $record it's giving right content . But If I am trying to send mandrill throwing api key error . Now If I remove $blog->title , $dsc the mail is working . But I need the blog title and description in my mail . 
Please help me. I am not getting any solution or help from any where. Your small help will be great from me.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue adding htmlentities() to my contents . like `htmlentities($blog->title )`